# How do i predict with standard errors using betareg package in R?

Tags: r, standard-error, beta-regression

I'm using 'betareg' package in R to perform beta regression. predict() function with se.fit=T is supposed to return standard errors along with the prediction but it doesn't. Is there any other way I can get the standard error outputs?

I'm open to using other packages that can perform beta regression too.

Answer (score 6):

I've thought about two alternatives to get the prediction interval of the mean of the response:

- The paper [Ferrari, S.L.P., and Cribari-Neto, F. (2004). Beta Regression for Modeling Rates and Proportions. Journal of Applied Statistics, 31(7), 799–815.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.ime.usp.br/~sferrari/beta.pdf&ei=Fmr-Ur-kFrLFsASah4A4&usg=AFQjCNEqKBmOb6SuwnTGZaF-2-jQT4q10Q&sig2=u7JdC8duGUZm-covmT2oMQ&bvm=bv.61535280,d.cWc) (which is in the `betareg` function references) presents the math formula (in Appendix B) to calculate the exact interval for a given confidence value. But it doesn't seem easy to implement.
- Estimate prediction interval through bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the package 'effects' and the function allEffects()

```
BetaReg <- betareg(Value~x, data = Data)
Effects <- as.data.frame(allEffects(BetaReg, xlevels=list(x=BetaReg$x)))$x
Effects
```

I think it is correct (looks about right on a graph) :)